# Al desactivar commandButton no ejecuta metodo del bean ubicado en el action del botón

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Estoy trabajando con jsf2 y primefaces. Tengo una pagina donde hay una tabla p:dataTable a la que he puesto checkbox:

```
            <p:dataTable id="listTable" var="bean"
                     value="#{beanMaquina.lstMaquinas}"
                     selection="#{beanMaquina.lstMaquinasSeleccionadas}"
                     rowKey="#{bean.id}" >

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{beanMaquina.onRowSelect}" update=":form" />
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{beanMaquina.onRowUnselect}" update=":form" />          
            <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{beanMaquina.onRowSelect}" update=":form" />
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{beanMaquina.onRowUnselect}" update=":form" />

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" class="check" />
```

omito las columnas de la tabla por no tener relevancia. En esa misma página tengo unos botones para realizar las acciones Nuevo, modificar, eliminar.

```
            <span><p:commandButton class="boton" action="/views/empresa/nueva_empresa" immediate="true" title="#{msg.nuevo}" icon="fa fa-fw fa-plus" /></span>
        <span><p:commandButton class="boton" action="#{beanMaquina.modificar()}" disabled="#{beanMaquina.verBtnUnaSel}" title="#{msg.modificar}" icon="fa fa-fw fa-edit"/></span>
        <span><p:commandButton class="boton" action="#{beanMaquina.darBaja()}" disabled="#{beanMaquina.verBtnMultiSel}" title="#{msg.darBaja}" icon="fa fa-fw fa-remove"/></span>
```

Bien, la idea es la siguiente. 
* El botón de Nuevo (Insertar registro en BBDD) siempre está activo por lo tanto no afecta para nada asi que lo omitire en las siguientes descripciones.
* Cuando carga la pagina los botones permaneceran desabilitados (disabled). 
* Cuando seleccionamos un checkbox en la tabla se habilita el boton de modificar.
* Cuando seleccionamos mas de un checkbox en la tabla solo permanece activo el boton de eliminar.
Por logica solo podremos modificar un registro mientras que eliminar lo haremos con uno o varios registros.

Este comportamiento lo tengo hecho y funciona pero cuando pulso los botones de modificar o eliminar no se ejecutan sus correspondientes metodo en el Bean. sin embargo Si hago que los botones esten habilitados cuando cargo la pagina si que se ejecuatn los metodos de los botones y la funcionalidad de habilitar y desabilitar botones con los check tambien funciona, pero claro, falla que al cargar la pagina los botones deben estar desabilitados porque no hay ningún registro seleccionado en la tabla. Esto lo he probado con disabled y con redered y el resultado es el mismo.
Que solucion podría aplicar? Espero haberlo explicado bien.

---

No lo tengo desarrollado, sólo muestro mensajes:

```
public String modificar() {
    verMensajeInformacion(GlobalCons.MSG_MODIFICAR_OK);
    logger.info("Botón Modificar pulsado");
    return null;
}
```

---

me auto respondo a mi mismo. Básicamente la solución estaba en vez de usar disabled o rendered, usar style

Comment: Hola ... a ver si entendi bien... vos quieres que cuando la pagina se cargue los botones esten deshabilitados ?

Luego seleccionar un checkBox y que se habiliten para ejecutar metodos ?

Comment: @francisco castillo, Correcto

Comment: Por favor, podrias mostrar el método  modificar() del beanMaquina ?

Comment: Prueba a ponerles el immediate="true", para que puedas ver si las acciones no se están ejecutando por algún error de validación en el resto de la pantalla.

Comment: @Pablo eso ya lo probé y nada, hace lo mismo

Comment: Deberías colgar el código completo

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto un fragmento de codigo que utilizo y tiene una funcionalidad similiar a la tuya.

Boton Nuevo (activa otros botones)

```
 <p:commandButton value="Nueva Factura" 
                  actionListener="#{facturaDataController.numeracionLegajoAlumno()}"
                  icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
                  update=":formFactura"
                  action="#{facturaDataController.activarBotones()}"/>
```

Metodo activarBotones()

```
public void activarBotones() {
    enabled = true;
}
```

Método desactivarBotones()

```
 public void desactivarBotones() {
    enabled = false;
}
```

Botón Registrar (Por defecto esta inactivo)

```
<p:commandButton value="Registrar" icon="ui-icon-check"
                 actionListener="#{facturaDataController.registrar()}"
                 disabled="#{!facturaDataController.enabled}"                                          update=":formFactura,:dlgFormPrestamo:tablaCuota,dlgFormPrestamo:tablaPrestamo"
                 ajax="false"/>
```

Finalmente metodo registrar()

```
public void registrar() {

    try {
        // Aqui iria la logica de tu metodo

        // Muestra mensaje de exito
        JSFUtil.addSuccessMessage("Factura registrada exitosamente");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // muestra mensaje de error
        JSFUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // aqui deberias limpiar los campos del formulario o si quieres desactivar botones
this.desactivarBotones();
}
```

Espero te sirva .. saludos.

Comment: Los botones Nuevo y registar estan en la misma pagina? si es asi y el boton registrar inicia desactivado, cuando lo activas y lo pulsas te llama al metodo registrar del bean?. Porque eso traducido a mi codigo es lo que no me haria, una vez activado el boton no me haria la llamada al metodo del bean. Basicamente tu codigo es similar a lo que yo tengo

Comment: Así es . Ambos están en la misma pagina